# To Read a double value out of a longer C# string

Tags: c#

I have a string that goes like "-23.45m / abc = 53.02m/s" that I want to take apart.  You'd think there was an easy way in .net to get the -23.45 (like using a built-in float interpreter) and tell me that the rest of the string starts at 'm'.

In C++ I would use

```
double num;
wchar_t* input_text = L"-23.45m / abc = 53.02m/s";
if (swscanf(input_text, L"%lf%n", &num, &count) == EOF)
  return false;
pos += count;
```

Comment: Is the string always in that same format? You could use RegEx or just string functions to pull out the numbers into their own strings.

Comment: The string always starts with the number? And which number formats are valid, and which culture does the number use?

Comment: You could use a regex that pulls out a floating-point number from the beginning of the string - match that for the `float`, then save the rest of the string

Comment: You say that in C++ you would use `scanf("%lf", &val);` what logic would you use in C++ to find `val`?

Comment: It's for a programming language, so the number format is fixed and basic.  I'd accept what C# accepts.

Comment: C# accepts a lot, there are even strange formats where parentheses stand for negative numbers. By default it uses the current culture, which is likely not what you want. So you should come up with a clear specification of what you want. If you make a decision on all the formats jon mentioned, we/you can create a regex that extracts the number part of the string.

Comment: So there's no equivalent of %lf, or no way to use like a Double.TryParse(text, out val)?  TryParse doesn't exactly the problem, but it's the idea for the easy way to read a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match the double value at the start. You'll need to consider what you want to support. For example, do you want to support all of these:

- .5 (no digits before decimal separator)
- +.5 (explicit +)
- 15 (no decimal separator)
- 1e-5 (scientific notation)
- 1,000 (thousands separator)

You should also consider what culture you want to parse in - "1,000" can mean "one thousand" or "one point zero zero zero" depending on your culture.

Once you've got your specifications nailed down, writing a regex shouldn't be too hard. That will let you match the double value in one capture and the rest of the string in another.

Comment: I honestly don't care :, just so long as it's defined and can handle integers.  Well if I have to go RegEx, then I can try to make something that works:  -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+    And then we have to figure out how to to a RegEx that eats that stuff, gives me a number, and tells me where to continue tokenizing.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: The regex wouldn't give you a number - the regex would give you the number part for you to parse with `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`, and the rest of the string.

Comment: Which kind of begs the question: If there's a simple way to parse a number, why can't I easily use that to extract the number in the first place?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: Because the parsing methods assume (reasonably, IMO) that extraneous data at the end of the string indicates an error. Personally I think it's the C standard libraries which did the wrong thing here, not .NET. IMO, it's much more common to want to *fail* on input of "456xyz" than to succeed.

Comment: Okay, but it makes things so much harder.  If I got 456.0 and "xyz", a simple if-statement would allow me to report an error if I want.  As is, I have to build a complicated RegEx.  Thanks for your direction, Jon

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: It makes it harder for *your* case - but simpler for everyone else's. How *exactly* would you go about detecting the "456xyz" bearing in mind it could have been "456.00xyz" or "456.00000000001xyz"? Basically you'd be doing the same thing as we're doing here - but I believe that's the more common case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8602/discussion-between-alan-baljeu-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: Sorry, that doesn't work for the way I work I'm afraid.

Comment: (Sorry, just trying to follow SO's wishes.) I guess there's no point in discussing as the feature isn't there.  But to answer your question, "scan until the number ends.  Check if the string is exhausted".  But I have to reinvent the C# number parser because I can't use it.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: If you consider "scan until the number ends" easy, can't you do that in *your* situation?

Comment: We're getting wires crossed.  I thought you meant if a number recognizer like scanf were given.  As is, I'm currently struggling to put together a RegEx that does this.